# Problems with input while compilation in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, input, sublimetext3

There was a problem with compiling the code in the Sublime Text 3 editor. Namely: (I show on the example of a calculator in C ++) when an action is entered (by pressing Enter) nothing happens, only the cursor moves to the next line.

This problem is present when compiling all programs (I tried it in Python and C++), where keyboard input is needed.

p.s If anyone needs it: then the compiler that I use for C++ is gcc.

[image]

Code:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
 char op;
float num1, num2;

cout << "Enter operator: ";
cin >> op;

cout << "Enter two operands: ";
cin >> num1 >> num2;

switch(op)
{
    case '+':
        cout << num1+num2;
        break;

    case '-':
        cout << num1-num2;
        break;

    case '*':
        cout << num1*num2;
        break;

    case '/':
        cout << num1/num2;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code please?

Comment: @Hemil I'll give u code. But when I checked it in other IDE, it works normally

Comment: Sublime doesn't support running interactive programs unless you use a third party package. This is a very common problem (see [these search results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sublime+input)). You want to use [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) for this.